# NotifyIcon stays on taskbar when app closes in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net

NotifyIcon stays on taskbar when application closed, then when I move mouseover it, it disappears.

I tried this on shutdown,

```
Private Sub MyApplication_Shutdown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shutdown
    Form2.NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
    Form2.NotifyIcon1.Dispose()
End Sub
```

It still stays, any suggestion on this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [Issue with NotifyIcon not dissappearing on Winforms App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067844/issue-with-notifyicon-not-dissappearing-on-winforms-app)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works when calling `Application.DoEvents()` after settings `Icon` to `null` and disposing the `NotifyIcon`.

```
Private Sub MyApplication_Shutdown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shutdown
    Form2.NotifyIcon1.Icon = Nothing;
    Form2.NotifyIcon1.Dispose()
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
End Sub
```