# Why can't I make my NotifyIcon implemented in another class disappear upon exit?

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

Here's some code from a freshly made Windows Forms project, with nothing else changed:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Bitmap blah = new Bitmap(16, 16);
        using (Graphics blah2 = Graphics.FromImage(blah))
        {
            blah2.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));
        }
        NotifyIcon2 n = new NotifyIcon2();
        n.NotifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        n.NotifyIcon.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(blah.GetHicon());
        n.NotifyIcon.Visible = true;
    }

    class NotifyIcon2 : IDisposable
    {
        public NotifyIcon NotifyIcon { get; set; }

        private bool disposed;

        ~NotifyIcon2()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this); // The finalise process no longer needs to be run for this
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposeManagedResources)
        {
            if (!disposed)
            {
                try
                {
                    NotifyIcon.Dispose();
                }
                catch { }
                disposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From what I can see, in `protected virtual void Dispose`, the `NotifyIcon` has already been disposed when it gets executed (explaining why I put a try/catch block there), so I can't do anything about its icon.

So how do I make it disappear?

Comment: Take a look at the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067844/issue-with-notifyicon-not-dissappearing-on-winforms-app and see if they help. As far as I've researched, apparently it's just Windows being absent-minded when it comes to notification icons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out disposing of the parent class will take out the child along with it.

`FormClosing += (sender, e) => n.Dispose();`

(see the link provided in BoltClock's comment on the question)